# Testing parsing of Spark SQL statements

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently writing a Spark application (Spark 3.0.1) in Scala (Scala 2.12.12) and would like to unit test the sql statements to check they can be parsed correctly. So for example, I’d like check that:

```
SELECT a_column 
From a_table
```

Parses correctly, whilst

```
SELECT a_column
a_table
```

Should fail

I have tried the following:

```
val query =
  """SELECT
    | *
    | FROM a_table
    |  """.stripMargin

val parser = spark.sessionState.sqlParser
val queryParsingResult = Try(parser.parseExpression(query))

assert(queryParsingResult.isSuccess)
```

Which passes, however when change the query to a simple select:

```
val query =
  """SELECT
    | a_column
    | FROM a_table
    |  """.stripMargin

val parser = spark.sessionState.sqlParser
val queryParsingResult = Try(parser.parseExpression(query))

assert(queryParsingResult.isSuccess)
```

This test fails with a “*mismatched input 'FROM' expecting {, ‘-‘}*” exception.

I've tried a few different variants of this approach, but can't seem to get anywhere.
Is there a way to parse these statements as part of the unit tests? Also for more complicated queries would I need to provide access to the hivemeta store so that the query parser could understand the underlying data schema of the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `parser.parsePlan` instead of `parser.parseExpression`. The second query doesn't show an error for `parsePlan`.

However, note that

```
SELECT a_column
a_table
```

is a valid query, which is equivalent to `SELECT a_column AS a_table`.